# Union e conversão de tipos

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, conversão-de-tipo

Pesquisando sobre unions encontrei a seguinte informação:

*Unions são geralmente usadas para conversões de tipo. Por exemplo, podemos usar uma union para escrever a representação binário de um inteiro em um arquivo em disco.*

*Primeiro criamos uma união entre um inteiro e uma matriz de 2 bytes:*

```
union pw {
int i;
char ch[2];
};
```

*Então, uma função que imprime os valores:*

```
putw(union pw word, FILE *fp)
{
    //  Escreve a primeira metade
    putc(word->ch[0], fp);
    //  Escreve a segunda metade
    putc(word->ch[1], fp);
}
```

Não entendi muito bem o que o autor quis dizer com essa exemplificação. Ele quis dizer que através de uma union poderíamos utilizar, por exemplo, um inteiro como char? Existe algum outro exemplo relacionado a conversão de tipos utilizando unions? 
Outra dúvida: segundo os argumentos da função criada, ela iria receber uma union por cópia/valor, já que não há um especificador de ponteiro (*) na declaração, mas há a utilização de um ponteiro (->) no corpo da função.

Comment: Se fosse a você deixava de consultar a fonte a que foi buscar essa informação. Quem ensina devia no mínimo saber que um `int` ocupa 4 bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### O que são unions?

Uma `union` funciona como um bloco de memória que é usado para armazenar variáveis de diferentes tipos de forma que quando um novo valor é atribuído a qualquer um dos campos, a informação existente é sobrescrita com o novo valor. Ou seja, os campos compartilham o mesmo espaço na memória, ou parte dele (caso o campo for menor que o espaço total da union).

Assim, todos os campos da `union` começam no mesmo endereço de memória. Dessa forma você pode ir pegando pedaços do inteiro por vez e ir escrevendo eles no arquivo como fez.

### Unions vs Structs

Sei que isso não faz parte da tua pergunta, mas só pra fins de comparação, esse funcionamento difere das `struct`'s, onde cada campo tem seu endereço de memória distindo, seu espaço na memória. Ou seja, nas `struct`'s, cada campo tem seu valor e ao atribuir um valor a um campo, não muda o valor de outro. Nas `union`'s os campos tem o mesmo endereço de início.

### Sobre o teu exemplo

Deixando as peculiaridades um pouco de lado por questões didáticas, um inteiro (int) em c/c++ geralmente ocupa 4 bytes (32 bits) de memória (com um processador 32 bits). Então no seu exemplo, na verdade, não é a 'metade' que tá sendo impressa primeiro, e sim o primeiro byte do `int`, porque o tipo `char` ocupa 1 byte. Então no exemplo você escreveu os dois primeiros bytes do `int`.

### Exemplo simples de union

Aqui você pode ver como as `union`'s podem ser usadas pra 'pegar pedaços' de um inteiro ou outro tipo de informação:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// O tamanho que a union armazena na memória é o tamanho do maior campo da union
union MinhaUnion {
    uint32_t x; // ocupa 4 bytes de memória
    uint16_t y; // ocupa 2 bytes de memória
    uint8_t z; // ocupa 1 byte de memória
}; // tamanho total que a union ocupa na memória é 4 bytes.

int main() {
    MinhaUnion u;

    // coloca o inteiro nos 4 bytes da union
    u.x = 123456789;

    // pega o inteiro total, depois o valor inteiro dos dois primeiros bytes, depois o inteiro somente do primeiro byte
    printf("X = %d, Y = %d, Z = %d\n", u.x, u.y, u.z);

    return 0;
}
```

### Sobre os operadores -> e .

O operador `->` é usado com ponteiros, variáveis que contém endereços de memória. Quando uma variável é **passada por referência** (declarando o parâmetro como `int* i` por exemplo) ao referenciar membros da variável dentro da função, deve-se usar o operador `->`. Mas se a variável foi **passada por valor**, deve-se usar o operador `.` para referenciar os membros da `struct` ou `union` (ou métodos de um objeto, se você estiver usando C++). Modificando um pouco o exemplo cima, agora temos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// O tamanho que a union armazena na memória é o tamanho do maior campo da union
union MinhaUnion {
    uint32_t x; // ocupa 4 bytes de memória
    uint16_t y; // ocupa 2 bytes de memória
    uint8_t z; // ocupa 1 byte de memória
}; // tamanho total que a union ocupa na memória é 4 bytes.

int imprimeUnion(union MinhaUnion un) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    if (fp != NULL) {
        fprintf(fp, "X = %d, Y = %d, Z = %d\n", un->x, un->y, un->z);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    MinhaUnion u;

    // coloca o inteiro nos 4 bytes da union
    u.x = 123456789;

    // passa a union por valor e imprime os campos dela no arquivo
    imprimeUnion(u);

    return 0;
}
```

Veja o que o compilador diz sobre o código acima:

```
union_vs_struct.cpp: In function ‘int imprimeUnion(MinhaUnion)’:
union_vs_struct.cpp:18:51: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘MinhaUnion’
     fprintf(fp, "X = %d, Y = %d, Z = %d\n", un->x, un->y, un->z);
                                               ^
union_vs_struct.cpp:18:58: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘MinhaUnion’
     fprintf(fp, "X = %d, Y = %d, Z = %d\n", un->x, un->y, un->z);
                                                      ^
union_vs_struct.cpp:18:65: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘MinhaUnion’
     fprintf(fp, "X = %d, Y = %d, Z = %d\n", un->x, un->y, un->z);
```

Dizendo que o operando de `->` (a variável que foi passada por valor - `un`) não é um ponteiro. Agora, se você trocar `->` por `.`  ou mudar a declaração do parâmetro na função pra que a variável seja passada por referência, o código compila, depende do que você pretende fazer.

### Sobre a tal 'conversão'

Por fim, o que acontece não é uma "conversão" entre tipos. Mas como foi dito acima, pelo fato de todos os membros compartilharem o mesmo endereço de memória inicial, você pode pegar 'pedaços' do espaço de memória total da `union` e manipular eles através de outro campo (variável). Então se tiveres a seguinte `union` com dois campos:

```
union UNION {
    int num;
    char[4] vetor;
};
```

podes tratar o segundo byte do número como um char ao referenciar `vetor[1]` já que `vetor` e `num` referenciam o mesmo endereço de memória inicial.